# Too many MongoDB connections issue in PHP web services

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, aws-application-load-balancer, jenssegers-mongodb

We have written web services/ callbacks in **Laravel/Lumen** for Azure graph APIs. Our web services are hosted in **AWS ASG** with **Apache** and **PHP-FPM** on the server. Minimum pool in ASG is 4 and max is set at 10. For database we are using **MongoDB** that also hosted in AWS parallel to Lumen APIs. We are using [jenssegers/mongodb](https://packagist.org/packages/jenssegers/mongodb) package in Lumen for database connection/queries. We are receiving huge number of requests from Azure per second. Our project is related to email/mail boxes so traffic/requests are coming continuously upto ~60K/sec.

The problem is our MongoDB connections are increasing rapidly reaching upto 40K. How to manage these connections? As MongoDB connection limit is 50K and we are also expecting increase in traffic from Azure in future with product expansion.

Earlier PHP-FPM was setup with **dynamic** PM, we have now changed it to **ondemand** PM with following configs

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 100  
pm.process_idle_timeout = 20s;  
pm.min_spare_servers = 10  
pm.max_spare_servers = 20  
pm.start_servers = 10;
```

This has decrease connection count but not significantly (around ~5K).

Comment: How do these connections occur? Per request? Do you work with queues and workers?